# How to store all the lines of a output of git push command for bitbucket

Tags: git, shell, bitbucket

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

When you run this command for bitbucket, It gives you output like,

```
Counting objects:
remote:
remote: Create pull request for <branch>
remote: https://bitbucket.com/...
```

But When I try to store that output in the variable and print that variable, It gives me output like this,

```
a=$(git push -q -u origin <branch>)
echo $a
Branch <branch> set up to track remote branch <branch> from origin.
```

I want to store that the above output or I just want to store that pull request URL into a variable.

pull request URL is preferred the option.
Thank you

Comment: Minor note: it's bitbucket.org. Bitbucket.com just redirects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `git` output to a file:

```
git push -u origin mybranch &> /tmp/git-push-origin-mybranch.txt
```

and then store contents into a variable

```
git_result=$(cat /tmp/git-push-origin-mybranch.txt)
```

Comment: Is there any way to get only that url? @gogaz